# How to get the final pipeline from auto-sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So, I used `auto-sklearn` to train models on a dataset. And the final results concluded that `ExtraTreesRegressor` is performing the best.

But what I need is the final pipeline the module used to for the training?

How can I get this best performing pipeline from the auto-sklearn? What I am having is a `autosklearn.estimators.AutoSklearnRegressor` named as `model`.